# TODO list: create a new task direct to a blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

***These are the pages of my application:***

***first of all, the index:***

[image]

***then, if I press: "Add a New Task":***

[image]

***If I fill the fields and press: "add a new task", I have to direct to the index page, but I got a blank page:***

[image]

***If I refresh it, I got:***

[image]

**This is the file of: tasks_controller.rb:**

[image]

**and this is the file of: new.html.erb**

[image]

**My question is: how can I fix my problem and get the index page (tasks_path) instead of a blank page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't redirecting to the object itself.  If you do:

```
redirect_to @task, :notice => "Your post was saved"
```

You should be good to go.

Also, I should add that you have a problem with your script.  It's going to redirect no matter the format.  However based on your other code, it appears as though you are accepting JSON requests as well.  You should probably switch your code to this:

```
format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Your task was created.' }
format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
```

However your system will work as well since consuming APIs should redirect properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to the index of the same controller, you don't need to use the helper methods, you can simply write

```
flash[:notice] = 'your post was saved'
redirect_to action: "index"
```

Maybe you can set the notice in the same line, I'm not sure, but this way it should work.

Edit: Although I don't see why you get a blank page... maybe you should also post your index method/erb